# addressing an input stream in java ee project

Tags: java

i have a java ee project which has a text file that uses a xml for loading data but i cannot address the test file xml which is behind the java test file.
in the test file i use this statement:

```
InputStream inputFile = AddressTreeTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test/testAdr.xml");
```

but when i run the file inputFile is null.
what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"when i run the file inputFile is null" - this suggests that the directory containing the /test folder is not in the CLASSPATH.  If you put test/testAdr.xml in the CLASSPATH for your test case I believe your code will work as written.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (add "/")

```
InputStream inputFile = AddressTreeTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/test/testAdr.xml");
```